# Installation BigInsights 4.2

Tags: ambari, biginsights

I would like to ask you about instalation BigInsights 4.2 on centos 7. As far I know, now the instalation is only avaiable via kitematic or dockerhub, but kitematic is only avaiable for widnows or mac. If i want to install via dockerhub I have to download kitematic which is nto avaliable for linux. So my question is: how can I install BigInsights 4.2 on centos or linux systems?

What is more, I installed IBM IOP, is there any option to install services like BigInsights - BigSheet, BigInsights - Big SQL, BigInsights Data ServerManager via IBM IOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need kitematic to install from dockerhub.

On a linux machine with docker correctly setup, you should just be able to run:

```
docker pull ibmcom/iop-hadoop
```

I don't think you get the BigInsights services with IOP.  For those services I think you need the IBM BigInsights Quick Start docker image:

[image]